# pyqtdeploy: standart library and site-packages

Tags: ubuntu, deployment, pyqt5, pyqtdeploy

I am trying to build a pyqt5 project with pyqtdeploy on ubuntu.
It fails early on stating *Unable to freeze files* with the error message

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PyQt5/__init__.py'
```

In the **Locations** tab I set the **Standart library directory** to */usr/lib/python3.4* and if I change that it fails even earlier - but PyQt5 is in */usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5*
how do I let pyqtdeploy know correct path?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem but sadly it seems that it's not yet supported, as mentioned [here](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2014-May/034234.html). I wouldn't hold my breath about getting this soon, as that message is already > 1 year old.

Comment: You can try and uncheck all the Qt modules and manually add the packages under "Other packages".

Comment: Alternatively, you can replace `site-packages` -> `dist-packages` in the appropriate pyqtdeploy configs (e.g., pyqt4-win.cfg).